# Azimuth Elevation vs Spherical Coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I was wondering why spherical coordinates define the vertical angle to be measured from the z axis as shown:

[image]

It seems that spherical coordinates and azimuth elevation are very similar, except the angle is defined differently.

[image]

Is there any reason why mathematicians prefer to define the angle from the z axis, are any of the conversions made more convenient perhaps?

Comment: See [this page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SphericalCoords.aspx) from Paul's Online Notes (download the section if the MathJax doesn't load). With the angle defined from the $z$-axis, we have $z = \rho \cos \phi, r = \rho \sin \phi$, which feels more natural because of the 2D representation of polar coordinates.

Comment: +1 Also, enjoy your new reputation!

Comment: Thanks for that. But if you swapped the angle, you’d just swap sin an cos, I couldn’t find anything that gets easier as a result. It seems like a strange convention to me. I suppose that’s why it’s a convention

Answer (score 0):

Both of the diagrams above represent spherical coordinate systems. Both have an azimuthal angle (the one that goes around the *z* axis) and a polar angle. Your question is why the polar angle is sometimes measured down from the zenith or else up or down from the *xy* plane. Both are perfectly valid, and one is not easier than the other. But is one more natural?

The answer depends on what you are using the spherical coordinates for. From a pure mathematician's point of view, the spherical coordinate system is a 3D version of the polar coordinate system, and measuring the polar angle from zenith makes sense. Here, the angle ranges from 0 to 2π.

However, if you are working with geospatial or astronomical data where the *xy* plane is the reference, it makes much more sense to measure from there. For example, when you think about latitude and longitude coordinates on the Earth, the equator is latitude 0°, not 90° (if measured from the North Pole). It would be a nightmare to have to constantly convert polar angles back and forth from a range of [-π/2,π/2] to [0,π]. Astronomers also use this to define multiple reference planes, e.g. your local horizon, the Solar System ecliptic. This allows us to measure the angles from a specific reference rather than what is essentially an arbitrary point on the sky. When I try to find a star at a declination of 5°, it's far easier to find the horizon and look up a little than find a point high in the night sky with no reference and look down 85° (or constantly be subtracting a value from 90!).

Either way you are still working in a spherical coordinate system and the maths only differ slightly since your polar angle range is different, but the selection of the polar angle reference can make conceptualizing coordinates much easier.

Comment: "*the spherical coordinate system... the polar angle... ranges from $0$ to $2π$*" The polar angle here is typically defined on $[0,π],$ I believe; otherwise, ($\rho,$ azimuthal, polar)$=(3,-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$ would be a conflicting specification yet appear to those following the $[0,π]$ convention as a legitimate point.